# Cant Append options to a select dropdown dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i am creating a javascript function which when clicked will create two drop downs and one text box and will append the html to the container div

but the problem is that, somehow it can't append the oprions to the two drop downs.

Here's my script

```
var i = 0;
function add_relation()
{
    i = i + 1;
    var condition = $('<select />', {
                             'class'  : 'relation-select',
                             'id'     : 'condition_' + i,
                             'name'   : 'condition[]'
                         });

    var key = $('<select />', {
                             'class'  : 'relation-select',
                             'id'     : 'key_' + i,
                             'name'   : 'key[]'
                         });

    $("#key_"+i).append('<option value="">Select Key</option>' + 
                        '<option value="product_title">Title</option>' + 
                        '<option value="type">Type</option>' +
                        '<option value="product_price">Price</option>' +
                        '<option value="product_weight">Weight</option>');

    $("#condition_"+i).append('<option value="">Select Condition</option>'+
                        '<option value="is_equal_to">Is Equal To</option>'+
                        '<option value="is_greater_than">Is Greater Than</option>'+
                        '<option value="is_less_than">Is Less Than</option>'+
                        '<option value="starts_with">Starts With</option>'+
                        '<option value="ends_with">Ends With</option>'+
                        '<option value="contains">Contains</option>');

    var left = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-left','id'    : 'relation_' + i})
                    .append(condition)
                    .append(key)
                    .append($('<input />', {
                                 'class'  : 'relation-input',
                                 'id'     : 'constraint_' + i,
                                 'type' : 'text',
                                 'name'   : 'constraint[]',
                                 'data-provide' : 'typeahead',
                                 'data-items' : '2'
                             }));

    var right = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-right',
                            html : $('<buton />', 
                            {
                                'class' : 'btn',
                                'name' : 'btn[]',
                                'value': 'X'})
                            });

    var parent = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-parent_' + i})
                    .append(left)
                    .append(right);
    $("#relation_container").append(parent);
}
```

Comment: change $("#key_"+i).append to key.append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `condition` and `key` objects for select box. Use same objects instead of using `id` as select boxes not created yet so you cannot find them using `id`:

```
var i = 0;
    function add_relation()
    {
        i = i + 1;
        var condition = $('<select />', {
                                 'class'  : 'relation-select',
                                 'id'     : 'condition_' + i,
                                 'name'   : 'condition[]'
                             });

        var key = $('<select />', {
                                 'class'  : 'relation-select',
                                 'id'     : 'key_' + i,
                                 'name'   : 'key[]'
                             });
        //here use object directly instead of id
        $(key).append('<option value="">Select Key</option><option value="product_title">Title</option><option value="type">Type</option><option value="product_price">Price</option><option value="product_weight">Weight</option>');
        $(condition).append('<option value="">Select Condition</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="is_equal_to">Is Equal To</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="is_greater_than">Is Greater Than</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="is_less_than">Is Less Than</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="starts_with">Starts With</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="ends_with">Ends With</option>'+
                                                        '<option value="contains">Contains</option>');                           
        var left = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-left','id'    : 'relation_' + i}).append(condition).append(key).append($('<input />', {
                                 'class'  : 'relation-input',
                                 'id'     : 'constraint_' + i,
                                 'type' : 'text',
                                 'name'   : 'constraint[]',
                                 'data-provide' : 'typeahead',
                                 'data-items' : '2'

                             }));


        var right = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-right',html : $('<buton />', 
                                                                            {
                                                                            'class' : 'btn',
                                                                            'name' : 'btn[]',
                                                                            'value': 'X'})
                                                                    });


        var parent = $('<div />', {'class' : 'relation-parent_' + i}).append(left).append(right);
    $("#relation_container").append(parent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it was just silly of me to understand that thing.. Took me 2 hours trying to find the issue.